# UIPickerView : Change text size

Tags: swift, uipickerview, font-size

Im French but I will try to speak English^^
I have a pickerview and I want to change the font size of the picked text like this :
[image]

Any ideas ? (In swift :-)

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44223906/7313752

Comment: It’s not what I am looking for, I want to change the size of the picked text like in the photo, not all the rows