# Increase the Size of Picker in iOS - Swift 4

Tags: ios, uipickerview

I have an SB that look like this

[image]

It yields this result

I'm trying to increase the font of my picker.

**What would be the best way to about this ?**

Is this something that I can achieve via the storyboard settings?

I have this

```
extension ScreenTimeViewController : UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return component == 0 ? 25 : 61
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {

        if view != nil {
            view?.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
            view?.layer.cornerRadius = (view?.bounds.width)! / 2

            return view!
        } else {

            let newView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 110, height: 40))

            newView.layer.masksToBounds = false
            newView.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
            newView.layer.cornerRadius = newView.bounds.width / 2

            switch component {
            case 0:
                addLabel(in: newView, at: CGPoint(x: newView.bounds.minX + 20, y: newView.bounds.midY), text: "\(row)", color: .black)
            case 1:
                addLabel(in: newView, at: CGPoint(x: newView.bounds.minX + 20, y: newView.bounds.midY), text: "\(row)", color: .black)
            default:
                break
            }

            return newView
        }

    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, widthForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 110
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, rowHeightForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 50
    }


}
```

Comment: You need to stretch the picker view a bit more horizontally, then set its font. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44223862/how-do-i-change-the-font-size-in-a-uipickerview-in-swift-3/44223906

Comment: @Sweeper The answer showed Swift3, I was looking for something in Swift 4.

Comment: I believe it hasn't changed much. Just use the code from that question. If there are errors, Xcode will suggest fixes.

Comment: @Sweeper I tried the code from the post you suggested, I got the error : https://i.imgur.com/QwCDSzq.png

Comment: I didn't mean that you should directly copy and paste it... `<Data Array>` is a placeholder for the array of strings that is in the collection view. In this case, you could replace the whole `<Data Array>[row]` thing with just `"\(row)"`, since you are displaying the numbers 0 to 59.

Comment: @Sweeper I followed what you said again, I still don't see my picker size increase at all, also the style seem to be messed up. See it here : https://i.imgur.com/EJX2zYk.png

Answer (score 0):

Although you can customize the color of the picker to some extent but for font no possible option is available if you want a highly customizable picker refer to github projects

https://github.com/mithyer/DatePicker-Swift

https://github.com/itsmeichigo/DateTimePicker